# creating a local repository in Artifactory

Tags: ant, jenkins, artifactory

I've just started installing Jenkins along with Artifactory and Ivy at our company.

Jenkins will be calling our ant build scripts and these scripts will then turn to Ivy to retrieve jars from the local repo (only).

We would like to have 2 local repositories : 1 for our local artifacts and 1 for 3rd party jars.

Our intent is to make sure developers retrieve only 3rd party jars that have been "approved" by admin in Artifactory.

The build scripts would then fetch from the local repository.

So my questiona are : 
How do we setup a local repository to include the built artifacts?
How are 3rd party jars retrieved by Artifactory if it has no access to internet?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you need to manage a local repo? Why not just create a hosted repository on Artifactory and point ivy at that? The advantage is that you can centrally (using the GUI screens) manage the repository content.

Comment: I need a local repo because the server where Artifactory is installed has no access to internet.

Comment: But even without access to the internet a Maven repository manager can still host files. Much easier to build and maintain

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think I had misunderstood what you previously said. I agree with your suggestion. Sorry for misunderstanding, english is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but setting up the local repository for your build artifacts should be straightforward, just follow the [instructions in the Artifactory docs](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories).

You would need to configure your build system to publish new artifacts to Artifactory.  This is also straightforward if you're using a standard dependency management tool like Maven or Ivy, and is covered in the Artifactory docs.

Keeping a separate repo for 3rd party JARs is also not too hard; at my company we do this by submitting the JARs to source control, which triggers a build in our CI system that publishes the JARs to Artifactory.

If you want to give more details of your build and CI setup I can add additional guidelines.